# UITextView validation issue: iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to add below validation into `UITextView

**Allowed**

- Combination of character with a number and special character.
- Multi-line input is acceptable.
- Input beginning with special character and number accepted.

**Not Allowed**

- Only number
- Only special character Input is trimmed in the beginning and end for
  empty space or empty new line.

I have already used below regex but not getting output.

> [A-Za-z0-9*[ @$!%*#?&+?=.]])([a-zA-Z]

Any help would be appreciated.